# Deep reduce (pluck maybe?) of array of objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have lodash to use for this (or underscore). I am trying to take an array of objects and turn them into a boiled down array of objects. Let me show you.

```
$scope.myObject = [{
    name: 'Name1', 
    subs: [
        {
            name: 'Sub 1', 
            subs: [
                    {
                        name: 'Sub 1-1', 
                        apps: [
                            {
                            name: 'App 1' 
                            }
                        ]
                    }
            ],
            apps: [
                    {
                        name: 'App'
                    }
            ]
        }
```

That's the original objects (one node of it at least). And My desired effect is to boil it down to an array of objects that are just the 'apps'. As you see here the apps can fall on any level - so it needs to be some kind of a deep search/reduce. These objects can potentially go 10 levels deep and have an app array on any level. So I'm trying to boil it down to a flat array of just apps, so for example this object would turn into:

```
 [{'name' : 'App 1'},{'name' : 'App'}];
```

I'm still pretty new to this kind of object manipulation so I could use some guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function pluckRecursive(input, prop, collect) {
    collect = collect || [];

    if (_.isArray(input)) {
        _.forEach(input, function (value, key) {
            pluckRecursive(value, prop, collect);
        })    
    } else if (_.isObject(input)) {
        _.forEach(input, function (value, key) {
            if (key === prop) {
                collect.push(value);
            } else {
                pluckRecursive(value, prop, collect);
            }
        })    
    }

    return collect;
};
```

when used like

```
pluckRecursive($scope.myObject, 'apps')
```

returns:

```
[[{"name":"App 1"}], [{"name":"App"}]]
```

Use `_.flatten()` on that to get rid of the nested arrays.

Comment: This is fantastic, could you explain a little bit on how it works?

Comment: Uhh... Well I thought it was pretty obvious. :) If the input is an array, it recurses into each array member. If the input is an object, it recurses into each object member, *unless* the `key` for the object member is the one you are looking for. In this case it simply pushes it onto a result array (`collect`). This array is passed down into every recursive call (so that all calls push to the same array) and returned in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [deep-reduce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-reduce) like this:

```
const deepReduce = require('deep-reduce')

let apps = deepReduce($scope.myObject, (arr, value, path) => {
  if (path.match(/subs\.\d+\.apps\.\d+$/) {
    arr.push(value)
  }
  return arr
}, [], 'subs')
```

Explanation of the code:

- `(arr, value, path) => ...` is the reducer function. It should always return the accumulated value, here the array of apps. The accumulated value is passed to the reducer as the first argument.
- `value`, is any value in your object tree. It may be the `subs` array, objects inside the `subs` array, or leaf values like `subs.0.name`.
- `path` is where the current `value` passed is found. For example `subs.0.subs.0.apps`. Keys of arrays are digits, here `0`.
- `subs\.\d+\.apps\.\d+$` matches any path that ends in `subs.digit.apps.digit`. I've omitted `^` from the start, since some apps are nested in subs subs. You may try out the regexp here: https://regex101.com/r/n1RfVv/1
- `[]` is the initial value of `arr`.
- `'subs'` tell `deepReduce` to start at that path, meaning that `name` or any other property in the root object will **not** be traversed.

#### Speed

Depending on the size of your objects, this might be slow, as `deep-reduce` traverses the whole object tree. If possible, define the starting path to limit traversal, like `'subs'` is given in example above.

If your data source is not changing much, you might want to scrape the data source, clean it up, and provide your own api.

#### Inner workings

If you are interested in how `deep-reduce` works, you can read the code here: https://github.com/arve0/deep-reduce/blob/master/index.ts

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). The first one searches for apps anywhere, the second one only in nested `subs`.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const myObject = [{ name: 'Name1', subs: [{ name: 'Sub 1', subs: [{ name: 'Sub 1-1', apps: [{ name: 'App 1' }] }], apps: [{ name: 'App' }] }] }];

console.log(objectScan(['**.apps[*]'], { rtn: 'value' })(myObject));
// => [ { name: 'App' }, { name: 'App 1' } ]

console.log(objectScan(['**(^subs$).apps'], { rtn: 'value', useArraySelector: false })(myObject));
// => [ { name: 'App' }, { name: 'App 1' } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this natively using [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get)

```
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };
 
_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');
// => 3
 
_.get(object, ['a', '0', 'b', 'c']);
// => 3
 
_.get(object, 'a.b.c', 'default');
// => 'default'
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the question. The goal is to discover the elements dynamically. If the paths were already known this would be trivial (no need for lodash)